# Autocomplete no results message

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, autocomplete, thymeleaf

Hello i have this form with autocomplete and thymeleaf

```js
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
 /*<![CDATA[*/
 $(function(){
    var currencies = [];
    /*[# th:each="n : ${Locations}"]*/
    currencies.push( {'value':"[(${n.name})] [(${n.address})]", 'Id':"[(${n.id})]"} );
    /*[/]*/   
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
      lookup: currencies,
      onSelect: function (suggestion) {
       
        var Id = suggestion.Id; 
     var requestData = { Id: Id };
     yada.ajax([[@{/opinion}]], requestData, function(responseText, responseHtml) {
          $('div.Inner').replaceWith(responseHtml);
          yada.initHandlersOn(responseHtml);
    });
      }
    });
  });
 /*]]>*/
 </script>
```

```html
<div id="searchfield">
         <form>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          <input type="text" name="weblocation" class="biginput" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Search">
         </form>
       </div>
```

I want to display message, if no match terms : No result!

how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```js
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
   showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
   noSuggestionNotice: 'Not result',
```

Use noSuggesionNotice from devbridge guide : https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/pull/341/files?short_path=0730bb7